# recommended .gitignore configuration when developing RN app on windows and then pulling down the repo files to mac?

Tags: react-native

I developed my RN project on my Windows laptop.  I built, configured and deployed to Google Play.  Then I pushed these files to a new git repo and then pulled down the files from this repo to my Mac. When I open my React Native project in Xcode on my Mac via MyProject.xcodeproj, the following Buildtime error is displayed in Xcode:

> 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

The following answer in a Github thread appears to be the solution to my issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25838#issuecomment-535683708

The answer above includes the following step:

> “Navigate to node_modules/react-native/React and choose
>   React.xcodeproj.”

.gitignore is configured by default to exclude the node_modules dir from the repo.   However, the solution above describes using Xcode to add a file from the node_modules directory.  Should I configure my .gitignore file to exclude all node_modules contents with the exception of:

node_modules/react-native/React

Or even more specifically, exclude all contents of node_modules with the exception of:

node_modules/react-native/React.xcodeproj

I need to make sure that my repo includes all files which are required in order to build the RN successfully on my Mac.

Comment: Have you done `pod install` in the `ios` directory?

Comment: yep that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac you need to do a

```
pod install
```

in `ios` directory as well.